# how to update the index setting,mapping after creating the index in elastic search on node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to update setting and mapping for index after creating it in elastic search using node.js.When I try to update the mapping and settings values in index it would not change.it remains in default settings.Kindly suggest me the way to fix this. Here I mention the coding.

```
  fs.readFile('./article_settings.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    settingsValue = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("settings Json");
    console.log(settingsValue);
    return elasticClient.indices.putMapping({
            index: indexname,
            type : type_name,
            body: { "settings" : settingsValue}
    });

  });
  fs.readFile('./article_mapping.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mapping = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("Mapping Json");
    console.log(mapping);
    return elasticClient.indices.putMapping({
            index: indexname,
            type : type_name,
            body: {
                  "mappings":{
                      "articles" :{
                          "properties" : mapping

                      }
                    }
            }
    });
```

Which produces the Error like.

```
> Unhandled rejection Error: IndexMissingException[[mhcarticle] missing]
    at respond (/home/100095/nodesamp/MHC-Search/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:264:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/100095/nodesamp/MHC-Search/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:223:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/100095/nodesamp/MHC-Search/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:155:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/100095/nodesamp/MHC-Search/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2016-02-25T13:13:48Z
  Request complete

Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2016-02-25T13:13:48Z
  Request complete

Unhandled rejection Error: MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields:   [mappings : {articles={properties={id={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, refference_id={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, key={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, url={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, created_on={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, status={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, title={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, description={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, batch_id={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, thumbnail={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, reference_key_id={type=string, index=not_analyzed}}}}]]
    at respond (/home/100095/nodesamp/MHC-Search/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:264:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/100095/nodesamp/MHC-Search/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:223:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/100095/nodesamp/MHC-Search/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:155:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/100095/nodesamp/MHC-Search/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Kindly let me know how to fix this issue.Thanks in advance.

After I change the code based on comments it looks like :

```
function initMapping(indexname,type_name){
  var fs = require('fs');
  var mapping;
  console.log(type_name);
  if(type_name == "articles"){
      fs.readFile('./article_settings.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        settingsValue = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("settings Json");
        console.log(settingsValue);
        elasticClient.indices.close(indexname);
        return elasticClient.indices.putSettings({
                index: indexname,
                type : type_name,
                body: { "settings" : settingsValue}
        });

      });
      elasticClient.indices.open(indexname);
      fs.readFile('./article_mapping.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        mapping = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("Mapping Json");
        console.log(mapping);
        return elasticClient.indices.putMapping({
                index: indexname,
                type : type_name,
                body: {
                      "mappings":{
                          "articles" :{
                              "properties" : mapping

                          }
                        }
                }
        });

      });

  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `indices.putMapping` in order to modify the index settings. You need to call [`indices.putSettings`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-putsettings)  instead.

Comment: thanks for your response Val after I call indices.putSettings I get the following error  **ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Can't update non dynamic settings[[index.type, index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_lowercase.type, index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_lowercase.filter.0, index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_lowercase.tokenizer, index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_lowercase.filter.1]] for open indices [[Index]]]**   could you help me to fix it ?

Comment: When updating analyzers, you need to [close the index first and then re-open it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis). So in your case, you need to call [`indices.close`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-close), then `indices.putSettings` and finally [`indices.open`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-open)

Comment: HI @Val when I close and open the index it throws the **Unable to build a path with those params. Supply at least index**  Error . Could you assist me to fix it? .

Comment: Yes, but please update your question with an **UPDATE** section that shows the code you have now.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you what you're trying to said.

Comment: I simply would like to see your updated code that closes and opens the index and why it errors out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104838/discussion-between-mohan-and-val).