# How to close and open the elasticsearch index in node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Can any one suggest the way for how can I close the elastic search Index and open it after update the settings of the same index using Node.js.

Comment: Does this question relate to [your other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628456/how-to-update-the-index-setting-mapping-after-creating-the-index-in-elastic-sear)? If yes, I've shown the methods you need to call in order to do so.

Comment: yes this is related to that previous question.could you assist me to fix this?

Comment: Let's do it in the other question then, otherwise we're spreading too thin and make it hard for other people to follow.